# Умножение дивергенции на вектор это что, Уравнение Навье стокса?

Tags: математика, геометрия, визуализация, физика, моделирование

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что означает первая операция умножения

-(v * треугольник_перевернутый) * V  что это значит?
**Точнее что значит умножить на вектор скорости после**, вон тот второй после скобок  (v*∇) * v , допустим  дивергенцию я понял,но що значит умножить еще на вектор скорости после?
К примеру допустим такое поле скоростей по x, или пусть вектора скорости будут равны x=y (k,k)

- 2 2 2
- 2 2 1
- 2 1 2

дивергенция для точки x0=1,y0=1 будет (1-2)/2 +(1-2)/2 =-1/2-1/2=-1
Далее если я умножу эту -1 на (2,2)  и на -1, будет (2,2)
То есть  у меня получится что на след итерации, скорость в точке будет U=U0+a*dt=2+2=4

- 2 2 2
- 2 4 1
- 2 1 2

Но это противоречит реальности. Я ожидаю что скорость там будет где-то 1.7, но точно не 4, это вообще откуда.
Следовательно там   какое другое умножение.
А если допустим там такая матрица

- 0 0 0
- 0 0 10
- 0 10 0

То там дивергенция равна 10/2+10/2=10. А 10 умножить на 0 будет 0, То есть 9 эффекта
Или допустим

- 0 0 0
- 0 9 10
- 0 10 0

дивергенция равна 10/2+10/2=10, а 10 * 9= 90 !!!!!!! То есть +90 скорости получит, откуда как? Ну это уже точно фантастика.

Значит там 100% какое-то другое умножение, или еще какая-то операция. Может это типа  надо проекцию отложить дивергенции на Единичный вектор скорости, но не где это не написано. И везде  еще одно и тоже уравнения в 1000 разных видах.

Ссылка на хорошую статью, https://habr.com/ru/articles/470742/  Но там не разу не понятно для скорости, где вот это нахождение дивергенции, и умножение на скорость. И вообще зачем там написано что надо типа найти поле скоростей, если оно известно с прошлой итерации.

Comment: [Здесь уже разобрались?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1557199/)

Answer (score 0):

Из определения оператора *набла* в декартовой системе координат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

немедленно получаем

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Само собой, в другой системе координат формулы будут несколько иными.

Comment: а почему получается скаляр после умножения на вектор скорости? я ожидаю что-что типа (a,b) получится

Comment: У вас вектор скорости скалярно умножается на вектор оператора "набла". Получается скаляр, который затем умножается (читай: применяется) к вектору. Получается вектор. Что не так?...